# From your pocket I can scare. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> Found at the unlucky square
>   From your pocket I can scare
>   With precious metals, my premiere
>   A pet that dad and daughter share

Hint 1:

> Within a ball I make my lair
>  My wings are furled, a double pair

Hint 2 (Doesn't say much about the answer, but should help you find the group it belongs to):

> A tree-named teacher does declare
> Of your sex, they're unaware
> A catalogue they have to spare
> For the creatures that to catch, you dare

Who am I?

Comment: Final Fantasy: Worlds Apart!

Comment: Seems like something to do with pokemon, but I've never watched/played it, so I don't know which one...

Comment: @Alconja Well that narrows it down to 100 ... but the first and last lines have me stumped.

Comment: @No. 7892142  Actually that narrows it down to about 900 if we take into account all the generations.

Comment: @Zikato The third line, though..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's

> Crobat, a pokemon
> [image: Crobat]

Reasoning:

Found at the unlucky square

> Crobat is #169 in the [National Dex](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number), 13² = 169.

From your pocket I can scare

> Mentioned before, pocket monster

With precious metals, my premiere

> Crobat first appeared in Pokemon Generation II, Gold/Silver (which are precious metals).

A pet that dad and daughter share

> <s>Maybe something to do with how Crobat evolves by happiness? Not sure.</s>
> <s>Could also possibly have to do with how people of all generations can enjoy playing Pokemon games at this point.</s>
> With credit to tfitzger (comments below):
> Both Koga and his daughter Janine have trained Crobats.

--

The first hint explained:

> Within a ball I make my lair
> -- Pokemon live in Pokeballs.
> My wings are furled, a double pair
> -- Crobat has four wings, two pairs of two.

Comment: Yes! You haven't got the 4th line yet, though - whilst admittedly it's mostly in there to preserve the couplet scheme, it does also fit in with the answer somehow

Comment: @Logicianwithahat Doesn't have to do with the anime, does it?

Comment: Not really, no. Think of its type and the changes between games

Comment: Theres a note on the second table of Crobat's moves [here](http://veekun.com/dex/pokemon/crobat#moves) that states: _"Appears on a newly-hatched Pokémon, if the father had the same move."_ So it looks as though when a Crobat hatches it inherits the moves of it's father?

Comment: @Lighty_46 That's the case with any hatched pokemon, though.

Comment: @No.7892142 Ah, never played the later generations ... still applies though, just like the 5th hint applies to most Pokemon :)

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat My guess would be because both Koga and his daughter Janine have trained Crobats.

Comment: @tfitzger And you'd be right!

Answer (score 4):

This answer is a work in progress, I'll fill in the clues as I figure them out.

I think you are

> Aluminium

Found at the unlucky square

> The 13th element in the periodic table.

From your pocket I can scare

> This one I am unsure of. Could have something to do with cell phones containing aluminium and scaring someone when it rings? Seems like too much of a stretch.

With precious metals, my premiere

> Aluminium was initially classified as a precious metal due to the difficulty of extracting it from ore. This changed in the 1880s.

A pet that father and daughter share

> I don't have any ideas for this one yet.

Comment: Maybe a pocket knife made out of aluminium (yes some are made out of aluminium), the last one has me stomped too though. But this is by far the best fit for the first clue

Comment: You're closer with the first clue than anyone else, and I like your reasoning, but no, sadly

Comment: If I wanted to change the answer, would it be better to add a new answer, or edit the existing one?

Comment: @RootVegetable If its a completely new approach then go with a new answer, otherwise edit your existing one.

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be

> Money?

**Explanation line by line:**

Found at the unlucky square

> In the United States the 2$ bill is considered unlucky.

From your pocket I can scare

> Money is usually in your pockets and people complain about not having much.

With precious metals, my premiere

> Coins are made of metal.

A pet that father and daughter share

> Daughters are known to spend their fathers' money.

Answer (score 3):

As @Alconja states, I think it will be

> Pokemon

Found at the unlucky square

> Not sure, unlucky number is 13, but that is Weedle

From your pocket I can scare

> Pokemon are sometimes called pocket monsters and monsters do scare

With precious metals, my premiere

> Some pokemon connected to metal?

A pet that father and daughter share

> In pokemon world adults and kids alike train them

Within a ball I make my lair

> They are stored in pokeball

My wings are furled, a double pair

> So we are looking for a winged pokemon. Double pair usually means insect type.

So my guess would be

> Beedrill. It has double pair of wings and the drill fits the precious metals somehow.

**EDIT:** second set of hints has been revealed

A tree-named teacher does declare

> All of the pokemon professors are named like trees

Of your sex, they're unaware

> At the start of the game they ask you: "Are you a boy or a girl?"

A catalogue they have to spare

> They give you choice of 3 starting pokemon which differ each generation

So that leads me to:

> Assuming one of the 3 starter pokemon from first generation, only one of them has wings which is Charizard. It's number is 9 which is considered unlucky in Japanese culture (where pokemon come from)

Only thing I'm not getting is the line "
With precious metals, my premiere"

Comment: You're on the right lines, but the wrong member of the group. Slightly off with the first clue

Comment: I'll probably get it after I get home and google the other generations, I only remember the first one from top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

*(Just registered on this Stack Exchange site to post this, so don’t have enough rep to comment.)*

In addition to No. 7892142’s answer:

A pet that dad and daughter share

> In the Indigo League in Gold/Silver and HeartGold/SoulSilver, both Koga and his daughter Janine have a Crobat.

Comment: That line may have been a little obscure (since you already have the answer by the time you work it out), but yes!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's a

> Cell Phone

Found at the unlucky square

> This is the one I'm least sure about. Is it a reference to the use of mobile phones in city squares during the last few years protests?

From your pocket I can scare

> Ring! Ring!

With precious metals, my premiere

> They contain a bunch of rare earth elements and precious metals.

A pet that father and daughter share

> Office fathers and teenage daughters are often associated with phones/mobile devices.